# Are there any browser-based version control clients?

Tags: version-control, web, browser

On a network I use I'm not able to install any third-party applications.  There's just MS Office plus a web-browser.

But, I want to introduce some version control of the Excel spreadsheets I'm developing.

As I said, I can't install any other apps, so an SVN/Git client is out of the question.

Does anybody know of a VCS for which the client runs in a web-browser?  I need to add files, submit new versions, compare deltas, etc.

I'm not just looking for web-based read-only browsing of a repo - I need full functionality via the browser.

I welcome your thoughts.

Comment: Just trying to bump this five year old question up... any newer answers?

Answer (score 1):

Google Docs/Drive has versioning, comments, sharing, etc. and may be able to do everything you need.

Comment: Hi, good answer, though I suspect I would feel like putting a square peg in a round hole when I copy the contents of each document into a text-document, then repeating with each successive update.  But, good lateral thinking Bort.

Comment: You should be able to upload the excel files directly no?  I'm curious why you need to copy the contents to a text document.

Comment: Ooh, I see.  Yes, that would also be a viable strategy. I would invest some effort in trialling it, but unfortunately Google Docs (plus email, calendar) are blocked sites on this network - to ensure adherence to MS Office, would you believe...

Comment: Wow, that's unfortunate.  Though Microsoft has their counterpart to Google docs, Office 365.  Not free, of course.